# How can I display a default value in my Html.TextBoxFor() that can be edited by the user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using a TextBoxFor to display an editable field. I need this field to display a value of "150" but allow the value to be changed.

I have tried using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MembershipDues, new { @Value = "150" })` but this is not working for me.

**Here are my Model's Fields:**

```
[Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public decimal MonthlyPayment { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public decimal MaintenanceFees { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public decimal MembershipDues { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public decimal ExchangeFees { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Duration { get; set; }

    public decimal AnnualPayment { get; set; }
    public decimal AnnualMaintenance { get; set; }
    public decimal AnnualTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal TenYearPayment { get; set; }
    public decimal TenYearMaintenancePercentage { get; set; }
    public decimal TenYearMembershipAndExchange { get; set; }
    public decimal TenYearTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal AnnualVacationCost { get; set; }
```

**Here's my Action**

```
        [OutputCache(Duration = 60)]
    public ActionResult CalculationView()
    {         
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [OutputCache(Duration = 60)]
    public ActionResult Index(CalculaterModel cm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (cm.Duration == "Annual")
                cm.AnnualMaintenance = cm.CalculateMaintenanceFeesAnnually(cm.MaintenanceFees);
            else if (cm.Duration == "Monthly")
                cm.AnnualMaintenance = cm.CalculateMaintenanceFeesMonthly(cm.MaintenanceFees);

            cm.AnnualPayment = cm.MonthlyPayment * 12;
            cm.AnnualTotal = cm.AnnualPayment + cm.AnnualMaintenance;
            cm.TenYearPayment = cm.AnnualPayment * 10;

            decimal percentage = .08m;
            decimal cost;
            int i = 1;
            decimal rate = cm.AnnualMaintenance;
            while (i <= 10)
            {
                cost = rate * percentage;
                rate = cost + rate;
                cm.TenYearMaintenancePercentage = cm.TenYearMaintenancePercentage + rate;
                i++;
            }
            decimal MDF = cm.MembershipDues + cm.ExchangeFees;
            cm.TenYearMembershipAndExchange = MDF * 10;
            cm.TenYearTotal = cm.TenYearMembershipAndExchange + cm.TenYearMaintenancePercentage + cm.TenYearPayment;
            cm.AnnualVacationCost = cm.TenYearTotal / 10;
            return View(cm);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**I need for my textbox to display "150" and to be editable.**
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please clarify, when you say "not working" is it not displaying, or not editable or not saving?

Comment: There's an awful lot of business logic in your action method......

Comment: @John Mitchell ~ "not working" means the initial TextBoxFor displays "" when I need it to display "150".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a sometimes confusing issue where is you don't specify your model with your view you won't get default values set even if they are set using the Razor syntax.

Change

```
return View();
```

With

```
var cm = new CalculaterModel();
return View(cm);
```

And see if that works.

Comment: Replaced the View() in both places? with the View(cm) code? The amount of times this issue has caught me out is insane (ie default view with no model and no default showing)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did solve the problem. A noob mistake on my end. I have the CalculationView being called within another view, so the fix was adding the model to the view that calls the CalculationView. Thanks again!